# How to prevent Typescript from looking in parent node_modules folder

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-modules, angularfire

I've got an NPM package inside an another NPM package. The child package has some code like `import { range } from 'iter-tools'`. Even though the child package.json does NOT have a dependency for `iter-tools`, I am **NOT** getting any kind of Typescript compile error. Presumably this is because the module resolver / tsc is walking up to the parent `node_modules` folder to look for the dependency and finding it there. I do **NOT** want this to happen. I want to be given an error that I've forgotten to include `iter-tools` in the local child's dependency list. In other words, I want the child package to be somewhat self-contained. I can't figure out how to make this happen. I've done a lot of Googling and found similar questions but can't find an answer. Is there something I need to add to `tsconfig.json` or `package.json`?

The context of this question is I've got an Angular + Firebase repo. One of the server pieces is Firebase cloud functions - FCF. This lives in a `functions` folder with its own package.json, and this is a child folder of the project set up by the Angular CLI. I've had trouble deploying the FCF unless ALL the code it needs is contained within the FCF folder. Deployment won't work if some of the code and type definitions are grabbed in a higher-level node_modules folder, like in the Angular root. I want to get a compile error if I've forgotten to include a dependency in the package.json of FCF. Instead I don't get any compile error and just a deployment error.

My project also has a local NPM package with code that is shared between client and server and I want to ensure that package is self-contained - not reliant on a package.json file in a parent folder.

Comment: If you look at how `PACKAGE_RESOLVE()` works in the [nodejs ESM module loader](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_resolver_algorithm_specification), then you will see that it is built-into the loader to climb up the parent directory hierarchy looking for a module that wasn't found locally.

Comment: So you are saying there is no way to stop it?

Comment: You can look at all the loader steps there yourself and see if you see any way around it.  When just doing `import` with a plain filename (no path), I did not see a way to avoid looking up the hierarchy, but you can study the steps it follows to see if you see anything I didn't see.

Comment: I will assume this is the answer - can't do it. Bummer. I'm not experienced enough to go looking through the typescript or other components.