# How to prevent TypeScript from using dependency from a different node_modules directory?

Tags: typescript

Consider a repository structure that contains two TypeScript projects:

- `common`: Some common that is used by the frontend as well.
- `backend`: A code NodeJS server app.

The full minimal reproducing example is [here](https://github.com/bluenote10/js-debug-projects/tree/master/debug_ts_false_imports) on GitHub. The common code has a third-party dependency and looks like this for instance:

**`common/src/common.ts`**

```js
import daysjs from "dayjs";

export function helperFunction() {
  console.log(daysjs());
}
```

The backend uses this common code like this:

**`backend/src/backend.ts`**

```js
import { helperFunction } from "../../common/src/common";

console.log("Running backend");
helperFunction();
```

The backend uses a `tsconfig.json` that is closely following the [TypeScript-Node-Starter](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter/blob/master/tsconfig.json), with the addition that the path to the common code is added to `include` (but that doesn't seem to make a difference):

**`backend/tsconfig.json`**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*", "src/types/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "../common/src/common.ts"
  ]
}
```

Further:

- In `common/package.json` we have listed `dayjs` as a dependency, and we have done an `npm install` in common.
- In `backend/package.json` we **forgot** to list `dayjs` as a dependency!

In this case, we don't want the code in `backend` to compile in order see that we are missing a dependency. However, what we are observing in practice is that `npm build` in `backend` emits the code just fine without any error. Apparently it picks of the dependency from `common/node_modules` (deleting it makes the compilation fail). Looking at the emitted output, the compiler has chosen a appropriate root dir to reflect the cross-directory import:

```
dist
├── backend
│   └── src
│       ├── backend.js
│       └── backend.js.map
└── common
    └── src
        ├── common.js
        └── common.js.map
```

Now trying to run the backend code with `node ./dist/backend/src/backend.js` crashes with `Error: Cannot find module 'dayjs'`, because only the `node_modules` folder in the backend is considered, and it is clearly missing the dependency.

How can we force TypeScript to use only `backend/node_modules` to make sure that the compilation fails if there is a missing backend dependency?

---

Note that this is conceptually different to the question [How to prevent Typescript from looking in parent node_modules folder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66948907/1804173) -- a behavior is in line how nodejs resolves runtime dependencies.

Comment: @jonrsharpe But `common/node_modules` is not in the parent path if I am in the working directory `backend`. And apparently NodeJS does **not** see what TypeScript sees. If TypeScript were to behave exactly like NodeJS at runtime it shouldn't use `common/node_modules` at compile time.

Comment: Ah, I see, sorry

Comment: FYI Since this start to look like a bug, I've opened an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44362).